# how to over come Little endian to big endian problem in TFTP client and server communication.?

Tags: c++, endianness, tftp

i am creating WRQ packet for TFTP client in cPP. the code works fine in Little endian system (PC) and have proble m with Big Endian system while creating packets.

the code is

```
  #define TFTP_OPCODE_READ     1
  #define TFTP_OPCODE_WRITE    2
  #define TFTP_OPCODE_DATA     3
  #define TFTP_OPCODE_ACK      4
  #define TFTP_OPCODE_ERROR    5

  #define cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE 1024
  #define cTFTPPacket_DATA_SIZE 512

   #define TFTP_DEFAULT_TRANSFER_MODE "octet"           //"netascii", "octet", or "mail"

   typedef unsigned char BYTE;
   typedef unsigned short WORD;    

/////////////////////////      below is Packet.cpp file       ///////

bool cTFTPPacket::addByte(BYTE b) 
{
         if (mCurPacketSize >= cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE) 
          {
                return false;
          }
        mData[mCurPacketSize] = (unsigned char)b;
        mCurPacketSize++;
        return true;
}

 bool cTFTPPacket::addWord(WORD w) 
{
      if (!addByte(*(((BYTE*)&w)+1)))
    { 
    return false;
    }
    return (!addByte(*((BYTE*)&w)));
}

bool cTFTPPacket::addString(char* str) 
{
    int n = strlen(str);
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
      if (!addByte(*(str + i))) 
      {
          return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Expected packet is

`0x00 0x02 string 0x00 octet 0x00`

Obtain in big endian is

`0x02 0x00 string 0x00 octet 0x00`

Code to create the Packets are

```
 bool cTFTPPacket::createWRQ(char* filename) 
 {
 /*      structure is the same as RRQ  */
   clear();
   addWord(TFTP_OPCODE_WRITE);
   addString(filename);
   addByte(0);
   addString(TFTP_DEFAULT_TRANSFER_MODE);
   addByte(0);
   return true;
 }

  bool cTFTPPacket::createACK(int packet_num)
 {
   clear();
   addWord(TFTP_OPCODE_ACK);
   addWord(packet_num);
   return true;
 }


   bool cTFTPPacket::createData(int block, char* mData, int data_size) 
   {
    /*         2 bytes    2 bytes       n bytes
    ----------------------------------------
     DATA  | 03    |   Block #  |    Data    |
    ---------------------------------------- */
   clear();                     // to clean the memory location
   addWord(TFTP_OPCODE_DATA);
   addWord(block);
   addMemory(mData, data_size);
   return true;
 }

 bool cTFTPPacket::addMemory(char* buffer, int len) 
 {
   bool oStatus=false;
   if (mCurPacketSize + len >= cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE)  
   {
      cout<<("Packet max size exceeded");
      oStatus= false;
   }
   else
   {
   memcpy(&(mData[mCurPacketSize]), buffer, len);
   mCurPacketSize += len;
   oStatus= true;
    }
    return oStatus;
  }


      BYTE cTFTPPacket::getByte(int offset) 
  {
       return (BYTE)mData[offset];
  }

 WORD cTFTPPacket::getWord(int offset) 
{
    WORD hi = getByte(offset);
    //WORD lo = getByte(offset + 1);
    WORD lo = getByte(offset + 1);
    return ((hi<<8)|lo);
}

WORD cTFTPPacket::getNumber() 
{
    if (this->isData() || this->isACK()) 
    {
        return this->getWord(2);
    } 
    else        
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

 bool cTFTPPacket::getString(int offset, char* buffer, int len)
 {
bool oStatus=false;
    if (offset > mCurPacketSize)
    {
        oStatus=false;
    }
    else if (len < mCurPacketSize - offset) 
    {
        oStatus= false;
    }
    else
    {
    memcpy(buffer, &(mData[offset]), mCurPacketSize - offset);
    oStatus= true;
    }
     return oStatus;
 }

 bool cTFTPPacket::createError(int error_code, char* message) {

 /*        2 bytes  2 bytes        string    1 byte
      ----------------------------------------
    ERROR | 05    |  ErrorCode |   ErrMsg   |   0  |
      ----------------------------------------  */
    clear();
    addWord(TFTP_OPCODE_ERROR);
    addWord(error_code);
    addString(message);
    addByte(0);
    return true;

 }

 int cTFTPPacket::getSize() 
 {
    return mCurPacketSize;
 }

  bool cTFTPPacket::setSize(int size) 
  {
    if (size <= cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE) 
    {
            mCurPacketSize = size;
            return true;
    }
    else 
    {
            return false;
    }
  }

 bool cTFTPPacket::isRRQ() 
 {
    return (this->getWord(0) == TFTP_OPCODE_READ);
 }

  bool cTFTPPacket::isWRQ() 
  {
     return (this->getWord(0) == TFTP_OPCODE_WRITE);
   }

   bool cTFTPPacket::isACK() 
   {
     return (this->getWord(0) == TFTP_OPCODE_ACK);
     }
    bool cTFTPPacket::isData() {
      return (this->getWord(0) == TFTP_OPCODE_DATA);
    }

    bool cTFTPPacket::isError() 
    {
    return (this->getWord(0) == TFTP_OPCODE_ERROR);
     }

    void cTFTPPacket::clear()      
    {
         mCurPacketSize = 0;
         memset(mData, mCurPacketSize, cTFTPPacket_MAX_SIZE);
     }

     unsigned char* cTFTPPacket::getData(int offset) 
    {
      return &(mData[offset]);
      }

    bool cTFTPPacket::copyData(int offset, char* dest, int length) 
    {
     bool oStatus=false;
         if (offset > this->getSize()) 
        {
        oStatus= false;
    }
    else if (length < (this->getSize() - offset)) 
    {
        oStatus= false; 
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(dest, &(mData[offset]), (this->getSize()-offset));
        oStatus= true;
    }
    return oStatus;
 }

  void cTFTPPacket::dumpData() {
    xRM_DEBUG("\n--------------DATA DUMP---------------------\n");
    xRM_DEBUG("Size: " << mCurPacketSize );
    for (int i = 0; i < mCurPacketSize; i++) 
    {
            xRM_DEBUG(mData[i]);
            cout<<mData[i];
    }
   }

    cTFTPPacket::~cTFTPPacket() {

     }
```

i figured the proble is occuring in Addword and get Word  how to over come this problem.
and one more thing my server is little endian (normal linux machine) and hardware is big endian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "traditional" approach is to pretend that there are only two
possible orderings (although I've seen at least three), and that all
machines are twos complement with 8 bit bytes.  A better approach is to
process the numeric format logically.  For unsigned, something like:

```
void
insertUnsigned16Bits( char* dest, unsigned value )
{
    *dest ++ = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    *dest ++ = (value     ) & 0xFF;
}

unsigned
extractUnsigned16Bits( char const* source )
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    result |= (*source ++ & 0xFF) << 8;
    result |= (*source ++ & 0xFF);
    return result;
}
```

This easily extends to any size of unsigned integers that can be
represented on your machine.

For signed output, if the format specifies 2's complement, just convert
to unsigned—the standard requires such conversions to do the right
thing.  On input, to be really portable, you have to read into a larger
type, test whether the unsigned value you read is greater than the
maximum signed value, and if so, subtract the corresponding unsigned
max; on most machines, however, just reading into an unsigned, then
converting to the signed type will work.

Comment: Do you mean `htonl` when you write "traditional"? Because it appears to me that `htonl` isn't restricted that way.

Comment: `htonl` would be one of the traditional approaches.  But only on a restricted set of machines---it's not part of the C++ standard.  And it doesn't really solve the problem, since it doesn't address issues like alignment (or absence thereof).

Comment: I specifically meant the "two possible orderings". AFAICT a machine with native 1-3-2-4 ordering could still implement `htonl`. The C++ standard isn't that relevant IMO; the question already mentions TFTP  so standard socket APIs may be assumed.

Answer (score 1):

When you're dealing with the possibility of one of the machines involved being big endian you need to convert everything to network byte order when you send.

The functions you need are `htonl`, `htons` (host to network long / short)

When receiving the data you convert to whatever the local machine needs using the reverse; `ntohl` and `ntohs`. On the big endian machine these are no-op and the data remains unchanged. On the little endian machine they convert to the correct (little endian) byte order.

**Edit:** In reply to OP's comment below:

Your `WORD` is an `unsigned short`. This means you need to convert it using `htons()` in your `addWord()` function:

```
bool cTFTPPacket::addWord(WORD w) 
{
    w = htons(w);
    if (!addByte(*(((BYTE*)&w)+1)))
    { 
        return false;
    }
    return (!addByte(*((BYTE*)&w)));
}
```

And then reverse the process in your `getWord()` function:

```
WORD cTFTPPacket::getWord(int offset) 
{
    WORD hi = getByte(offset);
    //WORD lo = getByte(offset + 1);
    WORD lo = getByte(offset + 1);
    return nstoh((hi<<8)|lo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur Reply.. i searched in the net and came to know this functions. but i dont know where to use these in this code .This endian makes lot of confusion to me.. can u pls help me

Comment: See edit above. However, not understanding the underlying concept is going to hurt you in the future. Can I make my initial explanation clearer somehow?

Comment: Erm ... what don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach is to use `htons` (to convert a 16 bit value from host to network byte order) and `ntohs` (to convert from network to host byte order); similarly `ntohl` and `htonl` for 32bit values.